# SQLAlchemy creating tables in all engines despite concrete binds

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've created myself a `Connector` class which is importing `Table` classes from dynamically loaded python files in given locations.
I have two database targets - one specified by config and one in-memory.

```
class Connector(object):
    _target_module = "plugin.database"

    def __init__(self, driver, connection_string, **kwargs):
        self._engines = {
            "primary": create_engine(f"{driver}://{connection_string}", **kwargs),
            "memory": create_engine(f"sqlite:///:memory:"),
        }
        self._setup_tables()

    def _setup_tables(self):
        importable_classes = import_classes(...)

        # initialize classes
        logger.debug("Initializing database plugin classes: %s", importable_classes)
        for cls in importable_classes:
            cls.metadata.create_all(bind=self._engines[cls.__database__])
```

The problem is that even though every `.create_all()` call has specified `bind`, SQLAlchemy seems to always create ALL the tables in ALL the engines.
Did I miss something or is this intentional?

Thank you for your time,
Daniel

Comment: How is `cls.metadata` being set?

Comment: I'm using `declarative_base` from `sqlalchemy.ext.declarative` as base class for all the table classes. `cls.metadata` is already internal thing of SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, [metadata.create_all](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.create_all) will

> Create **all** tables stored in this metadata.

However, it accepts a `tables` argument which is

> Optional list of Table objects, which is a subset of the total tables in the MetaData

So you could pass a list of table objects to `cls.metadata.create_all` to condition which tables get created for a particular engine.

Comment: I've found the problem - since all tables shared same `declarative_base`, they were all part of the same `metadata` instance - that resulted in all tables being created many times in all available engines.

I've created one `declarative_base` for primary database and one for memory database - that solved the problem. Thank you!